# Why I can not access instance of list?

Tags: c#, list

Why I can not use this instance?

```
    class MainClass
    {

        List<int> d = new List<int> (5);
        // d[0] error
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            // d[0] error 
        }
    }
```

Why I can not use this object?

Comment: Can you clarify this a bit?  What can't you use?  Where?

Comment: When you get an error, *always* include it in the question... but only ask the question after you've searched for other questions about the same error, of which there are *lots*.

Comment: `d[0]` is not the instance of the list. It is one of the elements in the list.

Comment: @BrianRasmussen And getting that one item in the list requires first accessing the instance of the list, which he can't do.  This question [has a number of problems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28484537/why-i-can-not-access-instance-of-list#comment45291069_28484537), but that isn't really one of them.

Comment: I get that - I was just trying to clarify.

Comment: Static List<int> d = new List<int> (5);

Answer (score 6):

Your method is static and your field is not. That's why you can't access it.

If you read the error message you'd be able to figure it out by yourself:

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or
>   property '`SOTestProject.MainClass.d`'